# Google Cloud Debian VM. Node Red stops working

Tags: debian, virtual-machines

I am a Windows user trying to use Linux for my online server.
I am testing a Debian VM running on the Google Cloud.
There I installed Node-Red, Apache and mySQL.
Every day when I am going to start my testing Node-red is down, the VM, Apache and mySQL are running but for Node-Red I have to open the terminal console and type node-red start.

Assistance welcome.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a lots of different factors. In order to be able to give a better answer we would need to see your logs.
However, a few things that you should know either way. Debian (and other linux distors) use systemd for ensuring that a background service is running, and is starting up at boot time. So when you restart a computer systemd is responsible to start up all software's that you would like to run.

More about systemd [here](https://wiki.debian.org/systemd). Generally what you want is to have the application in an "enabled" state to ensure that it starts up after a reboot.

However, if you do not shut down your VM between your sessions, then the application is most likely crashing from a different factor. Crashing can be caused by lots of different things, and this is where the logs would be appreciated. To find logs about the application you can most likely find it in `/var/log/<application-name>/`. Or if you want to view them in real time you can do `sudo journalctl -fu <application-name>`

More info on journalctl can be found [here](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/systemd/journalctl.1.en.html).

Comment: Hi, I have done some tests: reinstalled Node-Red, removed VM and reinstalled it with Ubuntu with Node-Red and finally returned to Debian but this time installed Node-Red only, no other App and no flows. Same problem, after some time, say 6 hours, check NodeRed and it is no longer active but VM is running. /var/log/nose-red does not exist. As it takes so long to "crash" the ideal is to locate the log. How can I find it? Thanks

Comment: Problem apparently solved. Most install procedures I found at the interned install old versions of node.js, latest NodeRed recommends node.js 14 so I did a manual install of node.js 14 and used NodeRed install script for Raspberry Pi and NodeRed is running for more than 12hs without crashing. That is the first time it holds for so long. Thanks